# pytest is magically working / not working

Tags: python, pytest

Two different Terminal windows open.  Both set to the same dir.  The second one was created by doing a "New tab" while in the first one

In the first one:

```
me $ pytest test_MakeInfo.py 
================================================================================ test session starts =================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.4, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.0
rootdir: /Users/me/Documents/workspace-vsc/Pipeline/src/python
plugins: arraydiff-0.3, remotedata-0.3.2, doctestplus-0.4.0, openfiles-0.4.0
collected 12 items                                                                                                                                                                   

test_MakeInfo.py ............                                                                                                                                                  [100%]

================================================================================= 12 passed in 0.87s =================================================================================
me $ which pytest
/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/bin/pytest
```

In the second one:

```
me $ pytest test_MakeInfo.py 
================================================================================ test session starts =================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.4, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.0
rootdir: /Users/me/Documents/workspace-vsc/Pipeline/src/python
plugins: arraydiff-0.3, remotedata-0.3.2, doctestplus-0.4.0, openfiles-0.4.0
collected 0 items / 1 error                                                                                                                                                          

======================================================================================= ERRORS =======================================================================================
_________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting test_MakeInfo.py __________________________________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/me/Documents/workspace-vsc/Pipeline/src/python/test_MakeInfo.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test_MakeInfo.py:6: in <module>
    from MakeInfo import main, makeInfo, makeTumorInfo, _getNormalTumorInfo
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MakeInfo'
============================================================================== short test summary info ===============================================================================
ERROR test_MakeInfo.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
================================================================================== 1 error in 0.17s ==================================================================================
me $ which pytest
/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/bin/pytest
```

What environment variables should I be looking at for differences?  Because so far as I can tell everything's the same between the two

Comment: Check your `PYTHONPATH` and `PATH` environment variables.

Comment: @flakes Yes, it was set in the first die, and didn't carry over to the second
Make this an answer and I'll give you the green checkmark.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check your `PYTHONPATH` and `PATH` environment variables.

Depending on the shell you use, they may not have been set the same when opening a new tab.

For example, in bash, you could append the required directory to your path using `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Sadly, I have multiple places where I'm developing my python code, with mutually incompatable source trees, so I can't do it on a machine-wide basis

Comment: @GregDougherty I usually create a virtual environment for every python project I work on. And source each env separately before testing.

Comment: How do you do that?  Link to discussion?  Thank you

Comment: @GregDougherty Try this https://medium.com/@dakota.lillie/an-introduction-to-virtual-environments-in-python-ce16cda92853